# portainer-ce container failed - exec: "sh": executable file not found

Tags: docker, portainer

I was trying to run Portainer as a container pretty much verbatim from: https://documentation.portainer.io/v2.0/deploy/ceinstalldocker/

```
docker volume create portainer_data
docker run -d -p 8000:8000 -p 9000:9000 --name=portainer --restart=always -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock -v portainer_data:/data portainer/portainer-ce
```

But the container is showing this error: \

> OCI runtime exec failed: exec failed: container_linux.go:380: starting
> container process caused: exec: "sh": executable file not found in
> $PATH: unknown

The web page at port 9000 just shows "Loading Portainer..." and is stuck there.  So, it appears the app has not properly started.

What should I do to get the container to start properly?

Running Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS

Comment: On its face, that error message seems likely to mean exactly what it says. Does the container _have_ a `sh`? What's the PATH?

Comment: ...a Dockerfile would go a long way towards providing enough information for this to be debuggable.

Comment: (If you're just trying to _use_ a Docker image someone else built, that's not necessarily really on-topic here, insofar as we're narrowly focused on software development; if you're trying to _fix_ the Docker image by modifying its definition, that's _definitely_ on-topic, but [mre] guidance applies).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Thanks.  Yea, I was trying to shell into it but essentially got the same error.   Seemed strange since it's the basic example that Portainer supplies.   I'll dig more to see what the Dockerfile. Rather new to docker, in general.

Comment: One notable thing about Docker is that it's very possible, and in some places intentionally good practice, to build a container that has only _one_ executable, the application the container exists to support. So there _may genuinely not be_ a `/bin/sh`... but then, if that's the situation, running the container as the folks who built it intended would be invoking whatever the executable it _actually has_ is.

Comment: (note that `RUN somecommand --arg` invokes `["sh", "-c", "somecommand --arg"]`; whereas `RUN ["/bin/somecommand", "--arg"]` invokes `["/bin/somecommand", "--arg"]` -- no `sh -c` involved. So if the original `RUN` they provided was in the latter form and you substituted something in the former, that would make a single-binary container fail)

Comment: It's absent due to security
https://github.com/portainer/portainer/issues/2768